# fscanf("%s%s", comet, group);

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    FILE *fin = fopen ("ride.in", "r");
    FILE *fout = fopen ("ride.out", "w");

    char group[6], comet[6];
    fscanf(fin, "%s%s", comet, group);

    int i = 0, n = 1, m = 1;
    while(group[i])
        n *= (group[i++] - 'A' + 1);

    i = 0;
    while(comet[i])
        m *= (comet[i++] - 'A' + 1);

    fprintf(fout, "%s\n", (n % 47 == m % 47)? "GO" : "STAY");

    exit (0);
}
```

ride.in:

```
COMETQ
HVNGAT
```

The answer should be "GO",but I always get "STAY".
I used dbg and found that comet[0] is '\000'.
I'm not very familiar with fscanf, so what happened in `fscanf(fin,"%s%s",comet,group);`?

Comment: You should enlarge `comet` and `group`'s size first. 6-element char array is not enough for 6-character string.

Comment: @timrau Oh yes! You're right. It's OK now!:D

Answer (score 0):

Both `comet` and `group` has size 6, but your input strings are 6 characters long, which requires 7-element arrays to store correctly (1 for the terminating `'\0'`). Thus, the `fscanf()` leads to out-of-bound array access and *undefined behavior*.